# Redshift multi-region replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, replication

I am looking to replicate Amazon Redshift data to a different region. However, Redshift does allow replication for backup reason only. What I am looking for is to process the data in one region and then replicate the processed data to another region so that tools in the second region can directly connect to Redshift in that region with lower latency.

I know I can [Build Multi-AZ or Multi-Region Amazon Redshift Clusters | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-multi-az-or-multi-region-amazon-redshift-clusters/) using Kinesis but since it is not a transactional app we really don't want to do that.

Comment: When you say "process the data in one region", is that data being processed _within_ Redshift, or is it being processed outside of Redshift and then is loaded into Redshift? How much of the data is changing (eg most of the data in the cluster, or just a small portion)? Is it just a few tables, or is it many related tables? Can you just write a script to `UNLOAD` the data from one cluster, then `COPY` the data into another cluster?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Processing of data is being done outside Redshift and then loaded into Redshift. Data will change a lot. it will be a batch processing twice a day.  There will be 150+ tables changing. We thought about loading the data and unloading it but one caveat this approach will not work if redshift cluster is on another AWS cluster which is a high possibility in my case

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by "if redshift cluster is on another AWS cluster"? If all the data processing is being done outside of Redshift and the results are merely loaded into Redshift, could you simply load that data into multiple Redshift clusters?

Comment: You mention that your goal is to reduce latency. However, most of the time for a query is likely to be taken with the query generation, rather than the network latency. I would recommend measuring the network latency from your desired locations (run the same query, measure response time) to determine whether it is worth the extra effort and expense.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sorry, What i meant was "if redshift cluster is on another AWS account". That's a fair point we should measure network latency but even though it might be that much but still it will be if somehow we can reduce it that would be great.

Comment: Launching duplicate Redshift clusters will incur additional expense, plus your time to manage the replication. It would be worth determining the benefits to know whether they are worth the additional cost.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes I agree

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Interesting stats, Difference between two regions is approximately 7- 8 seconds for a query. However, it's not network latency. For some reason query executed from the same region seems to have been cached compared to the query executed from  other region. So in first round difference is approx 300 ms for both regions. but from subsequent rounds difference is 7-8  Seconds.

Comment: Yes, there is result caching. You can turn it off for testing purposes. See: [Performance - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_challenges_achieving_high_performance_queries.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, I did set up `enable_result_cache_for_session` to `off` from psql console in both session and both region and result shown above are after setting it off only. I am quite not able to figure out why query from same region will be cached and not from other region.